# Trouble setting ubuntu vhost file

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

Ok.  I'm trying to set my config files in ubuntu.

When I look in the `sites-available` folder, I see

- `000-default.conf`
- `ssl-default.conf`

I have a site testsite.com that I need to configure the vhost for https

1. Can I just add a new vhost section to `ssl-default.conf`?  Should I copy the entire file to testsite.conf and make my edits there?
2. Where should I put the set up for port 80?  `000-default.conf`?  if I copy the file, do I need to add the `000` to the file name so that it is read first?
3. where can I put the info that used to be in the default file ie( `Allow Overrides`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best place for a VirtualHost is a new file in the sites-available folder.prfixed with a number like `100-`.

So something like `sites-available/100-443-myproject.example.com`.

This way when you will use the `ae2ensite` and `a2dissite` commands you will have the default and the `myproject.example.com` in lists of websites to enable or disable.

`000` is the reserved number fr the default Virtualhost, as apache reads files from sites-enabled directory in alphabetic order, and the default virtualhost should be the first one (the default virtualhost catch all bad formatted host HTTP header, when no `VirtualHost` `ServerName` is matching).

If your VirtualHost is for the port 80 you will have to use a `<VirtualHost *:80>` configuration directive (or `<VirtualHost <my IP>:80>`, depends of the `NameVirtualHost` setting). If your VirtualHost is for the SSL port, and it's your case, You will have to use `<VirtualHost *:443>`, and you will have to ensure with `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` that this Virtualhost is the only SSL enabled VirtualHost defined (so ssl-default shouldn't be enabled).

With port 80 the `ServerName` instruction is enough for apache to decide which VirtualHost should be taken. With port 443 and SSL this is not enough as SSL negociation is made before the Host header/`ServerName` can be matched. So Multiple SSL Vh have to use different ports or use the new SNI system [as described here for example](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts).

Now for the `AllowOverride` you do not need to put that in main configuration (but you could, using the `/etc/apache2/conf.d` directory for such shared-by-all Virtualhosts configuration stuff). Your VirtualHost can contain enough instructions, like:

```
<Virtualhost (....)
    ServerName (...)
    (...)
    <Directory />
      # Forbid .htaccess for all the filesystem directory tree
      AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /path/to/somewhere>
      # I am mad and I like slow apache server
      # So I want to allow .htaccess files
      # Instead of putting all the content of this .htaccess right here
      # in a Directory section
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  GOing to delete all the old files and start over.  I think I may have an additional question, but let's see first